# check to see if a specific glyphicon is on the page, if so--change to something else

Tags: jquery, css, glyphicons

I am trying to create a function that checks to see if a specific glyhphicon is on the page, if so I want it to display something else.

here is my code but no luck

```js
var span;
$('span').each(function(){
  if($(this).html() == 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok'){
    $(this).parent('li').html('✔').css({"color" : "blue"});
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Jquery `.attr()` method to save the day

By using the `.attr()` method we can get any attribute of an element.

So by using: `$(this).attr('class')` we can see if it matches the glyphicon you want to replace and chang it's value as you had described.

Bellow is a working example.

```js
var span;
$('span').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('class') == 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok'){
    $(this).html('✔').css({"color" : "blue"});
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.glyphicon-ok').each(
    function(){
         $(this).parent().html('✔').css({"color" : "blue"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery hasClass() function to check if the element has the specified class. This function returns true/false.

```
if($(this).hasClass("glyphicon-ok")) {
    // do something
}
```